# Modify variable value inside a jquery-modal event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm trying to modify the value of a variable inside a `BEFORE_CLOSE` event, with no luck so far... I'm using [Kylefox's Jquery-modal](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal)

HTML:

```
<div id="other" class="modal" style="display:none;">
<label for="form_otherName" class="label-important required">(*) Enter 'Other' Name </label>
<input type="text" required="required" name="form[otherName]" class="round default-width-input" id="simple-input">
<a href="#close" rel="modal:close">Close window</a></div>
```

Js:

```
      $('#form_submit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $("#carousel").rcarousel("getCurrentPage");
        var employeeID = $("input[name='form[employeeID]']").val();
        var temp = '';
       if (page == 4) {
            $('#other').modal();
            $('#other').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
                temp = $("input[name='form[otherName]']").val();
                console.log(temp);
            });
            console.log('after event '+temp);
            $.post("{{ path("working_letter_model",{'language': 'spanish'})}}", {model: page, idNumber: employeeID}, function (data) {
                //do whatever with the response

                });
            }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway to fix this?

I read about Js using variables for value instead of reference but I don't know if this applies.

Comment: your after event log isn't actually happening after the event

Comment: You don't set `temp` until the user closes the modal. You're calling `console.log` when you first open the page.

Comment: I think I should've posted the complete code, it's up now @Barmar

Comment: Your changes don't affect what I said. You're still logging `after event` immediately after binding the event handler, not after the event is triggered.

Comment: Showing a dialog (modal or non-modal) is asynchronous. `$("#other").modal()` just modfiies the DOM so that the dialog appears, it doesn't wait for the user to close it before returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're assigning the temp variable, only in the way in which you're logging it. It seems as though you're reading this code and expecting it to execute in a linear fashion, that is, in the order in which it appears. Here's what's actually happening.

The event is registered here and a callback is provided to execute when the event fires.

```
$('#other').on($.modal.BEFORE_CLOSE, function (event, modal) {
    //this code does not execute yet!
    temp = $("input[name='form[otherName]']").val();
    console.log(temp); //it shows the value
});
```

Next, this line executes and temp still has its initial value.

```
console.log('after event '+temp); //it returns empty
```

Finally, when the modal closes, the callback is executed and you get the console log from within, which shows the newly assigned value.

```
temp = $("input[name='form[otherName]']").val();
console.log(temp); //it shows the value
```

Comment: I thought the flow was something like: "Form button is clicked, modal shows up, type info, clic on 'close modal' button which fires the event and then exists the event to send the info via $.post"

Comment: No. For it to work that way your post needs to be inside of the before_close event handler, as well as the logging. Currently your $.post is suffering from the same problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Does it make sense why? The purpose of that event handler is to define what happens when that event fires, so logically your post needs to happen within.